# Separate numerical and categorical variables

Tags: pandas, preprocessing, categorical-data, numerical

I have a dataset (42000, 10) which contains 7 categorical features and 3 numerical. I would like to separate both the numerical and categorical features into 2 different data frames i.e I would like 2 data frames where one contains only numerical data (42000, 3) and the other only categorical data (42000, 7), perform some pre-processing on both of them, and lastly concatenate them into one data frame.

So, my question is how do I separate my initial dataframe into 2 based on numerical and categorical data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to use `select_dtypes` method in Pandas.
This returns a subset of a dataframe based on the column dtypes:

```
      df_numerical_features = df.select_dtypes(include='number')
      df_categorical_features = df.select_dtypes(include='category')
```

[Reference documentation of `select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

This will also depend on the column datatypes of your dataframe.
Considering you have categorical columns and few columns are either int64 or float you can go for:

```
  df_numerical_features = df.select_dtypes(exclude='object')
  df_categorical_features = df.select_dtypes(include='object')
```

Use the include/exclude option to choose based on the dtype. Other dtype information is as shown below:

- To select all numeric types, use `np.number` or 'number'
- To select strings you must use the object dtype, but note that this will return all object dtype columns
- To select datetimes, use `np.datetime64`, 'datetime' or 'datetime64'
- To select timedeltas, use `np.timedelta64`, 'timedelta' or 'timedelta64'
- To select Pandas categorical dtypes, use 'category'
- To select Pandas datetimetz dtypes, use 'datetimetz' (new in 0.20.0) or 'datetime64[ns, tz]'